# If I use onPress on any of my buttons they all change state. I want independent states

Tags: react-native, button, state, onpress

If I use onPress on any of my buttons they all change state, they show the same value. I want them to be independent of each other using the same 2 functions (increment and decrement).

```
this.state = {
   packs: 0
};

incrementPacks = () => {
    this.setState({
      packs: this.state.packs + 1
    })
  }

  decrementPacks = () => {
    this.setState({
      packs: this.state.packs - 1
    })
  }

<View style={styles.iceBtnContainer}>
    <Button title='-' onPress={this.decrementPacks} />
    <Text style={styles.count}>{this.state.packs}</Text>
    <Button title='+' onPress={this.incrementPacks} />
</View>


<View style={styles.bufPadBtnContainer}>
    <Button title='-' onPress={this.decrementPacks} />
    <Text style={styles.count}>{this.state.packs}</Text>
    <Button title='+' onPress={this.incrementPacks} />
</View>
```

Comment: Are these all contained in the same parent object? If so, they'll all act on the same `this.state` which is why you are seeing this behavior. You would need to provide a separate ID for each count to make this work and do something like `onPress={() => this.decrementPacks(1)}` (where `1` is the ID of the particular count)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
this.state = {
   icePacks: 0,
   bufPadPacks: 0
};

incrementPacks = type => {
   if(type === "Ice") {
    this.setState({ icePacks: this.state.icePacks + 1 })
   } else if(type === "BufPad") {
    this.setState({ bufPadPacks: this.state.bufPadPacks + 1 })
  }

  }

  decrementPacks = type => {
   if(type === "Ice") {
    this.setState({ icePacks: this.state.icePacks - 1 })
   } else if(type === "BufPad") {
    this.setState({ bufPadPacks: this.state.bufPadPacks - 1 })
  }

  }

<View style={styles.iceBtnContainer}>
    <Button title='-' onPress={() => this.decrementPacks("Ice")} />
    <Text style={styles.count}>{this.state.icePacks}</Text>
    <Button title='+' onPress={() => this.incrementPacks("Ice")} />
</View>


<View style={styles.bufPadBtnContainer}>
    <Button title='-' onPress={() => this.decrementPacks("BufPad")} />
    <Text style={styles.count}>{this.state.bufPadPacks}</Text>
    <Button title='+' onPress={() => this.incrementPacks("BufPad")} />
</View>
```

Comment: hey thanks for the response. I get this error when nesting "Ice"  inside the button: Invariant Violation: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops. @bhupati

Comment: could you test with the updated one and are you using componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate lifecycle method?

Comment: Im not using either no. I'll give it a try now @bhupati

Comment: 1 thing though - I actually have 4 buttons but just posted 2 for simplicity. I assume this changes things does't it..thanks @bhupati

Comment: sorry i didn't get you what you mean. For 4 you can go with the same approach. could you accept the answer if it works. Thanks.

Comment: Yes. I'm going to give it a try. I will respond later probably as I have just finished work and have to go somewhere. I'll respond later. Thank you @bhupati